# パスの設定時のエラー

Tags: swift, xcode

パスの設定時に以下のコード中のコメントで示したようなエラーが出てしまいます。原因がわからないため、もしわかる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        .DocumentDirectory,
        .UserDomainMask, true)

    let documentsPath = paths[0]
　　 // Instance member 'paths' cannot be used in type 'ViewController
　　 // というエラーが出てしまいます。

    let path = (paths[0] as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("datastore.plist")
    print(paths)

    var user:NSDictionary = [
        "Name": "A",
        "Age": "B",
        "Sex": "C",
    ]

    let success = user.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    // Instance member 'user' cannot be used in type 'ViewController
    // というエラーが出てしまいます。

    //print(success)
    if success {
    print("success!")
    } else {
    print("failure!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

詳しい説明は、後からします。とりあえず、下のプログラムをコピー＆ペースとして、ビルドしてみてください。そして、シミュレータ上で、ボタン「Save」を押し、次にボタン「Read」を押します。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let saveButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 80.0, width: 120.0, height: 44.0))
        saveButton.setTitleColor(saveButton.tintColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        saveButton.setTitle("Save", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        saveButton.addTarget(self, action: "saveDictionary:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(saveButton)

        let readButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 220.0, y: 80.0, width: 120.0, height: 44.0))
        readButton.setTitleColor(saveButton.tintColor, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        readButton.setTitle("Read", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        readButton.addTarget(self, action: "readFile:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(readButton)

        textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 140.0, width: 280.0, height: 280.0))
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        textView.editable = false
        self.view.addSubview(textView)
    }

    func saveDictionary(sender: AnyObject) {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            .DocumentDirectory,
            .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0] as NSString
        let path = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("datastore.plist")
        print(paths)
        let user:NSDictionary = [
            "Name": "A",
            "Age": "B",
            "Sex": "C",
        ]

        let success = user.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

        //print(success)
        if success {
            print("success!")
        } else {
            print("failure!")
        }
    }

    func readFile(sender: AnyObject) {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            .DocumentDirectory,
            .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0] as NSString
        let path = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("datastore.plist")
        let theDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        if theDict != nil {
            textView.text = "\(theDict!)"
        } else {
            print("Failure")
        }
    }

}
```

「パスの設定時のエラー」どころか、その100段階前のところで起きているエラーだということがわかりますか？

クラスという形態を持ったプログラムを書くとき、「どこそこには、こういう用途のプログラムを記述する」というきまりごとがあります。表現を変えると、「ルール」ですね。ルールから外れることを書くと、「このままではビルドできません」と警告が出ます。赤色のエラーメッセージですね。
「原因がわからないため、」と質問者さんはおっしゃいますが、原因はルールに従った記述をしなかったことにあります。エラーにならないためには、まずクラスのプログラムをするルールを勉強しましょう。エラーメッセージは、そのルールに従った上で、なおおかしなところがあるという前提のものなので、ダイレクトに間違った箇所を指摘してはいません。
きっちりした「ルール」の説明は、専門書にゆだねることにして、ここでは典型的なクラスの記述のパターンを示すことにします。

```
class クラス名 : 継承するスーパークラス名 {
    インスタンス変数（プロパティ）
    イニシアライザ（init()）
    メソッド（func メソッド名()）
}
```

`UIViewController`のサブクラスの場合、初期化処理は、イニシアライザでなく、`viewDidLoad()`メソッドに書くことが推奨されています。（もちろんイニシアライザが不用というわけではありません。）

テストで、実行してみたいプログラムがあるとき、そのプログラムは、ボタンのアクションメソッドの中に実装するといいでしょう。先のサンプルプログラムは、その例です。ボタンを押したら、試したいプログラムが実行されるという形をとります。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。理解することができました。